# Suggestion about system arcitecture

Tags: service, redis, architecture, microservices

I have some question about system architecture. I am building a ticketing system. Basically, it is creating support tickets.

I am trying to figure out if I used the components in the right way.

On the first case senario:

[image]

Client request to create a new ticket, the gateway forwards the request to ticketing service, ticketing service wants to check if the token valid so throws a publish through the nats with token, if the token is valid authentication service register token and info with a key-value pair to Redis for some time lets say 30 mins. and publish the result to nats. Nats redirects it to ticketing service the result. If everything is alright, ticketing service creates a record on the database.

Second case senorio is:

[image]

The user does the all steps above again, however, authentication side, instead of asking to authentication service gets the information from Redis if exists and does the same steps once again.

Here are my questions,

Do you think Redis is used for the right purpose? Or should I just remove it and ask over and over again when a request comes to authentication?

Do you think should I make all the authentication stuff on Gateway?

so it would look like this related to the above question.

On the initial login and request. (first case scenario)

[image]

After login, (second case scenario)

[image]

I would highly appreciate your suggestions, criticism and comments.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The more proper way is to do the authentication from the API gateway ie. API gateway authenticating with the authentication service as mentioned in your second option for the two solutions proposed.

The API gateway should prove to be the "gateway" of all your requests and filters any request that is not authenticated or authorized to reach your services. Authentication and authorization could be their own services in this case which API gateway will use to determine if a request can access any of the other downstream services. Aside from this fact, it also eliminates the complexity by removing the NATS. One less component to operate and manage is always a win.

One slight modification I would do is that on the second step, rather than the API gateway going directly to Redis, I would have the authentication service check Redis. In other words, the authentication service will go to Redis first before going to the database. That way, there's more decoupling.

The API gateway doesn't need to know how the authentication service stores the key for the token in Redis. So if you decide to change how the key should be in the authentication service, you won't have to effectively deploy a new change for how the key is read from Redis in the API gateway.

Comment: Hi Will, thank you very much for your response. It seems reasonable changes, however one thing is, do you think is redis efficent way to store the tokens? I thought i would put the token for lets say 30min long, after 30 min, authentication service will regenarate the token, and push the redis, for next 30 min instead of using the  database it will use redis to retrive the key. On the otherside i am thinking that, the query will be very spesific so maybe db can handle it alone. I am not sure if i am using the redis, for a real purpose.

Comment: A couple of notes, if you don't have a lot of load you may not need to use Redis although you can use Redis because they have TTL feature that automatically expires what is cached. I'm not sure there's an equivalent in SQL databases. To address the other issue, I would say the authentication service shouldn't refresh the tokens automatically if thats what you meant. There's much more complexity involved in that and could easily fall into a security trap of allowing a user access forever.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, it is very more clear for me now :)